# Exception while Passing nil as argument to stringWithString:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception

i have below 2 piece of code

In this case application did not crash.

```
[NSArray arrayWithArray:nil];
```

But if i am passing nil to `stringWithString:` application crashed.

```
[NSString stringWithString:nil];
```

> Result uncaught exception '`NSInvalidArgumentException`', reason: '*** -`[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]` nil argument'

What is the reason behind this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends 100% on the implementation of the method you are calling if a `nil` parameter is allowed. In general passing `nil` is allowed. But if you rely on a non-nil parameter to be passed in you could raise an exception.

Apple / the iOS developers *decided* that calling `arrayWithArray:nil` will result in an empty array.
For the `stringWithString:nil` they *decided* that you are not allowed to pass in `nil` and therefore raise an exception.

For the reason why they decided the way they did, you might want to go to the apple developer forums and ask the devs there.